# Why as per cppcoreguidelines, If the new and the delete are in a constructor/destructor pair,then it is a mistake

Tags: c++, oop

Why as per cppcoreguidelines,  If the new and the delete are in a constructor/destructor pair,then it is a mistake.
Could someone explain this...Please correct me if am understanding wrong.

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you provided the rule that you ask about.

Comment: Enforcement:If the new and the delete are in a constructor/destructor pair, mistakes can be flagged.

Comment: ES.61: Delete arrays using delete[] and non-arrays using delete

Comment: It's not saying that new/delete in constructor/destructor pairs is a mistake. It's saying "Detecting violations of ES.61 can be done if the new[] happens in a constructor and the delete (non-array) happens in a destructor."

Comment: Can you provide a link to these cppcoreguidelines?

Comment: @stefaanv First web search hit for "cppcoreguidelines". [Direct link to ES.61](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-del)

Comment: Generally, quote verbatim and link for context the original you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that rule, but that is exactly how smart pointers work and more general, it's used a lot in [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

One could say that it is a good rule of thumb to avoid the new-delete pair (and the C variants) because when things get a bit more complex, it's not always obvious to have exactly one delete for every new, creating memory leaks, dangling pointers and double deletes. That is why we have RAII and we use containers and smart pointers, but this rule is more general and less strict than the one in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain with an actual example, then go into details. Consider what happens if you have potentially throwing code between the new/delete pair; keep in mind that only fully constructed objects will have their destructor invoked:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

struct Type1 {
    Type1()
        : m1{new std::string(10u, ' ')} // string of 10 space chars allocated first
        , m2{new int[4'000'000'000u]} // may throw std::bad_alloc
    {
    } // fully constructed after ctor intit+body

    Type1(std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2)
        : m1{new std::string(s1, ' ')} // may throw std::bad_alloc
        , m2{new int[s2]} // may throw std::bad_alloc
    {
    } // fully constructed after ctor intit+body

    ~Type1()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor called\n";
        delete m1;
        delete[] m2;
    }

    std::string* m1;
    int* m2;
};

int main()
{
    try {
        Type1 v1;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
        std::cout << "v1.m1 is leaked\n";
    }

    try {
        Type1 v1{1u, 4'000'000'000u};
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
        std::cout << "v1.m1 is leaked\n";
    }
}
```

For actual output: https://godbolt.org/z/YcKMjrs9x

The answer to this strongly related to the notion of [*Exception Safety*](https://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html), which is not explicitly defined in the CppCoreGuidelines -- although conformance an interface to the weakest Exception Safety model does follow from the application/interaction of multiple guidelines.

Informally, the Exception Safety is a kind of post-condition contract on a function's (documented) interface that precisely defines the observable side-effects of this function if any exception is actually thrown from within it at run-time.

Interpreting the CppCoreGuidelines as a hole (especially rule [E.6: Use RAII to prevent leaks](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e6-use-raii-to-prevent-leaks), one can deduce that the guidelines effectively mandates that any function must satisfy at least the *Basic Exception Guarantee*; which basically requires two things: no resources are leaked, and any objects modified must be in valid, possibly transient state.

The easiest way to enforce the Basic Exception Guarantee is to use RAII types everywhere: RAII composes up the Basic Guarantee implicitly when class data members are themselves RAII types -- in particular, applying the *Rule of Zero* gets you all special operations for free with *Zero bug*.

On the other hand, manual matching of new/delete pairs is almost never enough to ensure no resources are leaked (in current code base, or in the future as code evolves). The only legitimate use of non RAII types (when used as an *Owner*) is when implementing an RAII type; in which case, you'll have to be extremely careful in how you write code, in many different aspect. One such requirement is that any code that runs while a raw resource handle is held (by a local variable for instance) must satisfy *Noexcept Guarantees* and this requirement must not be dropped as the code base evolves.